# jQuery UI Tooltip - Return Position Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm trying to do what seems to be a simple task that would, in theory, return the "my" and "at" values of the position method for the tooltip based on the parent of the hovered element that initializes the tooltip but I'm not sure exactly how to do this.

```
var s,
TooltipController = {

settings: {
    tooltips: '[data-tooltip]'
},

init: function () {
    s = this.settings;
    this.bind_ui_actions();
},

bind_ui_actions: function () {
    $(s.tooltips).tooltip({
        content: function () {
            // Only return a tooltip if the content is truncated
            return ((this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth) ? $(this).data('tooltip') : false);
        },
        items: '[data-tooltip]',
        open: function (event, ui) {
            // If tooltip resides in a <th /> then use animations else dontuse animations
            var parent = TooltipController.get_tooltip_parent($(this));
            return ((parent == 'TH') ? ui.tooltip.animate({ top: ui.tooltip.position().top + -10 }, "fast") : false);
        },
        position: function(event, ui) {
            var parent = TooltipController.get_tooltip_parent($(this));
            var top_pos = ((parent == 'TH') ? '+10' : '');

            return { my: 'center bottom', at: 'center top' + top_pos };
        },
        show: { duration: 0 },
        tooltipClass: 'tooltip'
    });      
},

get_tooltip_parent: function ($this) {
    return $this[0].nodeName;
}
}
```

If I add console.logs to each of the methods I can see that the position method doesn't even get hit and I'm not exactly sure why.  I'm sure this is a simple noob mistake but I'm just not understanding whats happening.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think `position` can be a function? From the documentation, it can only be a plain object.

Comment: Thank you, Frederic.  You are absolutely correct and that was an oversight on my part.  In essence of this post, do you have a suggestion on how I could achieve this??

Comment: From your current code, it looks like you could unconditionally set `position` to `{ my: 'center bottom', at: 'center top' }`, then determine in your `open` handler whether or not the parent is a `<th>` and add ten pixels to `ui.tooltip.position` if it is.

Comment: I ended up going with a different solution and that was disabled jquery fx if the parent != 'TH' which ended up being exactly what I needed for the situation.  Thanks for your help and suggestions Frederic.